# What technique/pattern does cin/cout use allowing e.g. cout << x << y?

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns

In C++, we usually use many `<<` operator to output to console like below:

```
cout << "x = " << x; // Output, for ex: x = 5
```

I know each `<<` operator return `cout` again, the code should be similar with:

```
some_class& do_some_thing(int x) {
    // process or print x
    return *this;
}
```

But I don't know what is this technique or pattern called and in what case we should use it?

Should this technique be implemented on another programming language, such as C#, which I'm using for my work.

Comment: Operator overloading??

Comment: The << and >> are shifting operators. Cout and Cin just have them overloaded (operator overloading). It isn't really a design pattern and I wouldn't recommend overloading them for your class unless it makes clear sense what they are supposed to do.

Comment: `some_class *do_some_thing(int x) { ... return this; }` should be some_class& do_some_thing(int x) { ... return *this; }` when supporting chaining.

Comment: @TonyD: Thank you, I have not spent much time on C++. I use Java and C# instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt the term is not "fluent interface". Fluent interface is just one use-case of method chaining. And operator streaming is definitely not fluent interface.

Comment: From the guys who claim to have coined the "fluent programming" term "You should choose your return type based on what you need to continue fluent action." - it's not even necessarily a reference to the current object.  Fluent interface is not some kind of subset of method chaining, but an orthogonal design approach which may use method chaining quite frequently but not exclusively.

Comment: @Barry: Then go post your answer to the older question.  We don't need comments like that spread over fifty questions, we need all comments and answers grouped, and fifty signposts to help with searching, since doing a keyword search for this concept without knowing its name(s) is a problem.  That's what "mark as duplicate" does, create signposts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). As an example, there's a boost library that provided a chaining way of assigning into a container before brace-initialization came around ([Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)):

```
vector<int> v; 
v += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

typedef pair< string,string > str_pair;
deque<str_pair> deq;
push_front( deq )( "foo", "bar")( "boo", "far" );
```

Typically though, you see it more in other languages to do things like providing a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). I don't see it that much in C++ personally, outside of streaming.

Comment: *"I don't see it that much in C++ personally, outside of streaming"* - `operator=`, `+=`, `*=`, `/=`, `&=`, `|=` etc. are other common examples.

Comment: @TonyD Those support it, yeah, but you don't really see `a += b += c += d` ever.

Comment: you haven't seen my code ;-).  More seriously, you do reasonably often see things like `a = b = c = d;`, 'x = ++y;' and occasionally things like `f(a += b);`.

Comment: @TonyD I wouldn't call those last two things chaining though. More just function composition.

Comment: Actually, neither assignment nor compound assignment operators are method chaining, because they group right-to-left.  You get `a.operator=(b.operator=(c.operator=(d)))` not `a.operator=(b).operator=(c).operator=(d)`

Comment: @BenVoigt: a good insight, but I don't see that that disqualifies it as method chaining... invoking further calls against the same object using the earlier-returned reference is the key factor.  Do you have some reference suggesting otherwise?